# drawViewHierarchyInRect only captures backgroundView from Mapbox on my devices

Tags: ios, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox iOS SDK 1.0.3, and on some occasions I want to blur the map view. This works fine on the simulator, but when I run it on the device, only the backgroundView and annotations get captured in the snapshot that I blur. I run into the same issue when I'm recording with Lookback - the entire map gets recorded on the simulator, but I only get the background and annotations on the phone.

I'm using GPUImage for the blurring, but ran into the same issue using CoreImage - the problem seems to be in the capturing of the image.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
- ( void ) blur {
    // Remove current blur if there is one
    self.blurOverlay.alpha = 0.0f;

    // Take a screenshot
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0 );
    [ self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO ];
    UIImage *copied = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Apply the blur filter
    GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter *blurFilter = [ [ GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc ] init ];
    UIImage *blurImage = [ blurFilter imageByFilteringImage:copied ];

    // Create the imageView and fade it in
    self.blurOverlay = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:blurImage ];
    [ self.blurOverlay setFrame:CGRectMake( 0, 0, blurImage.size.width, blurImage.size.height ) ];
    self.blurOverlay.alpha = 0.0f;
    [ self.view addSubview:self.blurOverlay ];
    [ self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.blurOverlay ];
    [ UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        self.blurOverlay.alpha = 1.0f;
    } ];
}
```

Methods I've used to capture the image:

```
[ self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO ];
[ self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES ];
[ self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ];
```

They all give the same results. Does anyone have any ideas of what the problem could be?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapbox's `RMMapView` is based on `CATiledLayer` & `UIScrollView`, so to capture a snapshot it requires a special API to synchronously draw the tiles into the context. Check out `-[RMMapView takeSnapshot]` and friends, which returns a `UIImage`.